# How to add Python Modules into catkin libraries so they can be imported by other packages

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to create some python modules which are common for multiple ros packages.
Can anyone guide me on how to list them in CMakeLists.txt file so they get insatlled in lib/python2.7/dist-packages directory?
So far I have tried adding following lines

```
 add_library(python_module_library scripts/common.py)
 set_target_properties(python_module_library
          PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_PYTHON_DESTINATION}
```

This is giving me CMake Error as:

```
 CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: python_module_library
 CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "python_module_library".
```

Any Ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202563/how-to-add-python-modules-into-catkin-libraries-so-they-can-be-imported-by-other-packages/) by [Jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/20150/jarvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at the [catkin documentation - User Guide - Handling of setup.py](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1